# Vue.js: Changes in Array Object Property Not Reflected in UI

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a Vue.js (version - 2.6.14) application where I have a hierarchical list of topics. Each topic can have child topics, and I'm using a recursive component to render the nested topics.

One of the properties on each topic object is showAddChildFormVal, which is initially set to false. I have a button for each topic that should toggle the value of showAddChildFormVal between true and false when clicked.

In my parent Vue component, I have a method toggleAddChildForm that updates the showAddChildFormVal property on the topic object. I can see in the console logs and Vue Devtools that the property is changing correctly, but the changes are not reflected in the UI.

I have verified that the showAddChildFormVal property is being updated correctly in the topic object within the topics array. However, when I try to display the value of showAddChildFormVal using the expression {{ topic.showAddChildFormVal }} in the template, it does not reflect the updated value.

I have also tried using this.$set to explicitly notify Vue about the property change, but it didn't resolve the issue.

I'm not sure why the changes in the showAddChildFormVal property are not being reflected in the UI. Is there something I'm missing or any additional steps I need to take to ensure proper reactivity of the array objects?

Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
Vue.component('topic-list', {
  props: ['topics'],
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li v-for="topic in topics" :key="topic.id">
        <div>
          <button @click="toggleAddChildForm(topic)">Toggle</button>
        </div>
        {{ topic.showAddChildFormVal }}
        <topic-list :topics="topic.children"></topic-list>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  methods: {
    toggleAddChildForm(topic) {
      this.$emit('toggle-add-child-form', topic);
    }
  }
});

// Parent Vue instance
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    topics: [
      { id: 1, showAddChildFormVal: false },
      { id: 2, parentId: 1, showAddChildFormVal: false },
      { id: 3, parentId: 1, showAddChildFormVal: false }
    ],
    hierarchicalList:[] // map of parent-child, calculated from topics. This is the value passed to child component
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAddChildForm(topic) {
      const topicAsli = this.findTopicById(topic.id);
      this.$set(topicAsli, 'showAddChildFormVal', !topic.showAddChildFormVal);
    },
    findTopicById(topicId) {
      // ...
    }
  }
});
```

HTML code is like this -

```
<div id="app">
  <topic-list @toggle-add-child-form="toggleAddChildForm"  :topics="hierarchicalList"></topic-list>
</div>
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the changes in the showAddChildFormVal property are reflected in the UI correctly.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is the problem but you are emitting an event from the child to the parent component:

```
  methods: {
    toggleAddChildForm(topic) {
      this.$emit('toggle-add-child-form', topic);
    }
  }
```

but not handling the event in the parent as you should:

```
<div id="app">
  <topic-list @toggle-add-child-form="toggleAddChildForm"  :topics="hierarchicalList"></topic-list>
</div>
```

Comment: That's there. forgot to mention. Now I updated my question. Thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 0):

The reactivity is not triggered because something inside the array gets changed, and not the array itself. The reactivity does not pick up on a change that subtle.

I know it's not an ideal solution, but one thing you could try is to re-set the whole array object by calling:

```
this.topics = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.topics));
```

This way the new array that you're setting is not in any way related to the old array, and therefore reactivity is triggered for sure.

Comment: This also didn't work. ChatGPT says - In Vue.js, the reactivity system is designed to detect changes not only when the array itself is modified (e.g., push, pop, splice) but also when the array's contents change. The reactivity system is capable of detecting changes to individual elements within an array, even if the array reference itself remains the same.

When you modify an array's element using Vue's reactivity system, it will trigger the necessary updates and re-render the affected parts of the template. This is achieved through the use of JavaScript's Object.defineProperty or Proxy.

Comment: You were right though Vue tracks only those member variables of an object which are present at the time of its first introduction in the scope of Vue. Example code given here has ```showAddChildFormVal``` part of the Object at the time of instantiation but in real it was not in my code and I was adding that later on hence it didn't have reactive property.